# UISearchDisplayController won't show up

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm confused right now.

I created a UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch and assigned it to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` which shows up like it should:

[image]

When initializing the item I assign an action that should be executed and it does:

```
- (void)searchForLocation
{
    NSLog(@"search for location");
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

But the UISearchDisplayController is not showing up after that call.

What am I missing here?? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search display controller is not something that "shows up". It is a controller, not a view. - Also, it must be associated with a UISearchBar, but I don't see one in your interface. It is for displaying a table containing *results* of a search; it does not *do* the search (nor does it provide interface to let the user do the search; *you* must do that).